# HTTP 405 api jquery ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to add member on myewellness.com

i am using jquery and php on a wordpress website, i have to collect the user's details and add him to myewellness.com
this is the link to their api documentation:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/pr6s7isht9ihdao/API-Services-Documentation-v2.0-1.pdf

but i am getting this on chrome:

```
OPTIONS https://api.myewellness.com/api/v1/services/membership/create send @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.2
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.myewellness.com/api/v1/services/membership/create. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
(index):1509 Failed: [object Object]
```

and CORS not enabled error on fire fox,

here is my js:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
    (function( $ ) {
      $(function() {
        $("#register_form").submit(function(){
            console.log("Wellness API Initiated!");

            var api_user_name = $("#user_name").val();
            var api_user_email = $("#user_email").val();
            var api_payment_first_name = $("#payment_first_name");
            var api_payment_last_name = $("#payment_last_name");
            var api_user_password = $("#user_password").val();
            var api_client_address_one = $("#client_address_one").val();
            var api_client_address_two = $("#client_address_two").val();
            var api_client_city = $("#client_city").val();
            var api_client_state = $("#client_state").val();
            var api_client_zip = $("#client_zip").val();
            var api_client_gender = $("#client_gender").val();
            var api_client_home_phone = $("#client_home_phone").val();
            var api_client_cell_phone = $("#client_cell_phone").val();
            var api_client_work_phone = $("#client_work_phone").val();
            var api_client_birth_date = $("#client_birth_date").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://api.MYEWELLNESS.com/api/v1/services/membership/create",
                /*headers: {
                    'Authorization':'Basic Vml0YWxhbGVydA==:MTI5OTky',
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
                },*/
                data: "user_name="+api_user_name+"&password="+api_user_password+"&first_name="+api_payment_first_name+"&last_name="+api_payment_last_name+"&address1="+api_client_address_one+"&address2="+api_client_address_two+"&city="+api_client_city+"&state="+api_client_state+"&country=US&zip="+api_client_zip+"&email="+api_user_email+"&phone="+api_client_home_phone+"&work_phone="+api_client_work_phone+"&cell_phone="+api_client_cell_phone+"&gender="+api_client_gender+"&birthdate="+api_client_birth_date,
                datatype: "json",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +"Vml0YWxhbGVydA==:MTI5OTky"); },
                success: function(msg){
                    console.log("Success: "+msg);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log("Failed: "+error);
                }
            });
            console.log("API Fire Complete!");
            return false;
        });
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Their server isn't giving you permission to instruct other people's browsers to access their API.

You shouldn't want to do that anyway - otherwise you will be handing over your API key to all your visitors!

Make the API requests from your server, using PHP, instead. You'll probably want to look at the [cURL library](http://php.net/curl/) to do that.

Comment: but when i remove the header, the api server says unauthorized, can't i just use the js to figure this out??

Comment: No, you can't. Use PHP.

Comment: please can you guide me how to do that??